# Как получать координаты движущегося объекта в реальном времени?

Tags: javascript, css

Добрый день! Есть элемент который анимируется с помощью css (transform: translateY). Нужно получать его координаты x и y на странице в реальном времени. Пробывал реализовать через getBoundingClientRect() , но он отображает только начальные координаты. Нужно реализовать на чистом JS, без библиотек. Для удобства: [пример на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hp06w4wq/)

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.rec {
  position: absolute;
  left: 220px;
  top: 260px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}

.animate {
  animation-name: moveup;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  
}

@keyframes moveup{
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-250px);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rec animate"></div>
  <div class="coord">22</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Есть такое событие `transitionend` - оно генерируется по окончанию анимации. Попробуйте использовать его

Comment: @Дмытрык  Зачем оно здесь ? Оно ведь только срабатывает после окончания анимации, а мне нужно в процессе выполнения

Comment: а..., попробуйте `setInterval`-ом запускать  `getBoundingClientRect()`. Таймер снимите привязавшись к `transitionend`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если правильно понял какой ожидается результат:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.rec {
  position: absolute;
  left: 220px;
  top: 260px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}

.animate {
  animation-name: moveup;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  
}

@keyframes moveup{
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-250px);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="rect" class="rec animate"></div>
  <div id="coord" class="coord">22</div>
</div>
<script>
   function changeCoord(timestamp){
   document.getElementById("coord").innerText = 
   document.getElementById("rect").getBoundingClientRect().top;
   requestAnimationFrame(changeCoord);
   };
   requestAnimationFrame(changeCoord);
</script>
```

Comment: Прикольно. Но, нужно отметить, что этот метод является эксперементальным. И даже у Моззилы пишут, через некоторое время от него могут отказаться. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame

Comment: @Дмытрык Можно всё то же самое повесить на простой setInterval

Comment: @Darth так как я писал в комментариях к вопросу?

Comment: @Дмытрык Тот случай, когда стоило попробовать написать ответ)